# Mapping values to xslt hidden field

Tags: c#, xslt

In my xslt I have this hidden input tag `hfHeaderLogId` that I want to set in the Handler. I have tried to use `XsltArgumentList` but that is not working. Is there any other way to do this and not return json I just returning the html

xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="//DrugCompendiumViewModel">
    <input type="hidden" id ="hfEventName" name="hfEventName"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfDDName" name="hfDDName"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfDDValue" name="hfDDValue"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfHeaderLogId" name="hfHeaderLogId" value ="0"/>
```

Handlers

```
        inputXML.LoadXml(result);
        inputXSL.Load(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/NoLongerRecommended.xslt"));
        var argsHeaderLogId = new XsltArgumentList();
        argsHeaderLogId.AddParam("hfHeaderLogId", "hfHeaderLogId", HeaderLogId);
        inputXSL.Transform(inputXML, argsHeaderLogId, context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: To use and reference a global parameter your C# code sets in the API your XSLT needs to declare a global `<xsl:param name="hfHeaderLogId"/>` and set e.g. `<input value="{$hfHeaderLogId}" .../>`.

Comment: thanks do I use the same `AddParam`?

Comment: With the example XSLT `<xsl:param name="hfHeaderLogId"/>` I have given the parameter is namespace less so your `AddParam` should set the local parameter name as e.g `hfHeaderLogId` but not pass a namespace; I currently don't remember which of the first two arguments to `AddParam` is the local name and which one is the namespace.

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam?view=net-6.0, the first argument is the local name, the second as the namespace should be the empty string `argsHeaderLogId.AddParam("hfHeaderLogId", "", HeaderLogId);`